# How can I make an addition of Hours with javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Having an array of values represented in seconds, I am trying to have a sum of them and represent them in hours. But the result of the values it's not working like I was expecting. Here is the code:

```
// Array of the times in seconds
var arr = [32400,33300,34440,14400,14400,14400],
    sum = 0;
// Trying to get the sum of the seconds in an array
arr.forEach(function(num){
     sum+=num ;
     console.log(num + " => " + moment.unix(num).utc().format('HH:mm'));
});
console.log(sum + " => " + moment.unix(sum).utc().format('HH:mm'))
```

The **result of the code** in console is this:

```
// The array values => With the moment.js time format
32400 => 09:00
33300 => 09:15
34440 => 09:34
14400 => 04:00
14400 => 04:00
14400 => 04:00
// The SUM of the arrays => With the moment.js time format
143340 => 15:49
```

The expected **result**:

**39:49**
    `(09:00 + 09:15 + 09:34 + 04:00 + 04:00 + 04:00 = 39:49)`

Comment: Where do you live that 39:49 is a valid time of day?

Comment: you can't get your expected results. you're building a date/time string, but require an **INTERVAL** string. moment is PROPERLY building what amounts to 1 day 15 hours 49 minutes.

Comment: Make your own custom function instead of loading such heavy framework. This should be contained in  less than 10 lines.

Comment: I am using the framework in the hole app to do other stuffs @G.Ghez...

Comment: Nice point of view @MarcB

Comment: @Antiga , I'll ignore your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use moment.js.

```
var arr = [32400,33300,34440,14400,14400,14400],
    sum = 0;
arr.forEach(function(num) { 
    sum+=num; 
});
var hours = Math.floor(sum/3600);
var minutes = Math.floor((sum%3600)/60);
console.log(hours + ':' + minutes);
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens because moment deals with time *instances*, not *durations* and `format('HH:mm')` returns the hours and minutes as time of day.

Instead, use the [duration API](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/):

```
moment.duration(sum, 'seconds').asHours()
```

Unfortunately that returns a floating-point number, which you will need to format into a `HH:mm` string manually.

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to do it with moment.js. I am accepting @ŁukaszKapica  solution because it's more complete and beacause of his thinking way to solve the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why do you want to use framework for such simple task, here is simple variant with custom function:

```js
function secAsHours(s) {
  var r = '' + (parseInt(s/60)%60);
  while (r.length<2) r = '0' + r;
  r = '' + parseInt(parseInt(s/60)/60) + ':' + r;
  while (r.length<5) r = '0' + r;
  return r;
}

var arr = [32400,33300,34440,14400,14400,14400];
var sum = 0;
arr.forEach(function(num){
    sum+=num;
    document.write(num + " => " + secAsHours(num) + "<br>");
});
document.write(sum + " => " + secAsHours(sum) + "<br>")
```

Comment: I'm using the framework in the app to do other stuff and I was trying to solve this problem with it also. But yes, there is others simple ways. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Because with Moment js you will get an valid date and of course there is no 39.45 in a day. What it does is just adding the numbers until it hit 24h and then starting again with 0. Why you have to use moment just add everything together and divide by 60